# Data recovery from erased drives whils installing OS from win 8 to Ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery

While installing Ubuntu 14.04 on a machine with windows 8.1 already installed I lost my D and E drives with the important personal Data. Is there any 
way that I can recover my data now that Ubuntu is running in my machine?

Comment: **BUT first: STOP** using your overwritten harddisk **NOW**!!!

Comment: ...and by the way: i assume you have only one harddrive in your machine, so *D:* and *E:* are just partitions?

Comment: Yes D & E: are partitions ..

Comment: Yes D: and E: are partitions and is the way i can get my data